# Lock orientation regardless of rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, orientation

I have a `UITabBar` application with embedded `UINavigation` for some of the views. On one specific navigationview I am displaying graphs/charts and it would be better to display them in `landscape` as if the iPhone was rotated to the left or right. The rest of the app is better suited to portrait. So I want to "force" the views containing graphs to load in landscape regardless of how the user has the device physically rotated. I've tried:

```
#pragma mark - Rotation
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

But this does not seem to do anything to the view. If I select the "Landscape Left" icon in the "Supported Interface Orientations" for my target then it allows the entire app to re-orientate on rotation of the device. Is there a way to lock my app in portrait for all normal views and lock in landscape for my views containing graphs such that the app ignores the actual device orientation?

Comment: Where is this method located?

Comment: What version of iOS and Xcode do you use?

Comment: The method resides in my UIViewController class for the specific view that I want to rotate/lock and I am using Xcode4.5. With all due respect @stackmonster, I am acting on advice from a User Experience expert from a top London agency. So the problem at the moment is that I **can't** pick and choose because I can't figure out how to do this rather than the other way around as you suspect. I have to admit that with the charts displayed in landscape, the usability is dramatically improved.

Comment: @stackmonster, I think I may have mis-communicated something. I want to understand your point because I am new to development for these devices. I don't want to provide something for them to click on to rotate the view. I want the view to always load in landscape and only landscape so that the scatter plots which are "wider" than they are "high" always display in landscape. When I was advised I was also shown examples of high-grossing apps which do the same thing and manage to remain intuitive to the user. Am I still missing your point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I am using iOS 6 SDK.

I am using a custom TabBar Controller. 
and controlling the orientation of that TabBar Controller by the below set of codes

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // You do not need this method if you are not supporting earlier iOS Versions
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

And the view controller should contain

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation);
}
```

This is what I did and was able to lock a view to landscape or portrait (in my case). To force may be you can put a alert view stating the user to turn the device to landscape and show him the graph. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. In tab bar applications it is not the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`: method of the individual view controllers being called. Only the tab bar controller's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is called to determine whether and how the views can be oriented.

However, the individual view controllers should implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` accordingly anyway. Those methods are still used to determine the orientation of animation effects when pushing or pulling a view controller.

I never tried the following myself: You could try subclassing the tab bar controller and respond to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` accordingly depending on which view is currently shown to the user. **But I fear that Apple has good reasons for forcing us to support the same orientations for all views within a tab bar app.**

Answer (score 0):

Try it in particular `ViewController` in which  you need to required in landscape mode:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight );

}
```