# Can i get/set the rotation lock status in device's setting on ios programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to set the status of "lock rotation" in device's setting programmatically. Is there anyway to do it?

[image: lock rotation]
<sub>(source: [lunascape.tv](http://www.lunascape.tv/products/iphone/iLunascape/img/en/Steave18_a.PNG))</sub>

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically set device orientation in iOS7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987249/how-do-i-programmatically-set-device-orientation-in-ios7)

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228758/lock-orientation-regardless-of-rotation