# Lock and unlock ViewController rotation objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

My app is by default only in portrait orientation, but in one **ViewController** I want to lock and unlock rotation in function of some actions.
In Android version, I do this task using Activity.setRequestOrientation with FULL_SENSOR or **PORTRAIT** and **LANDSCAPE** values.
Which is the equivalent in iOS?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock orientation regardless of rotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228758/lock-orientation-regardless-of-rotation)

Comment: user3086708 please try to search for an answer before posting a question, this question is quite common and has been already answered. In case you have specific issue that you believe is not covered yet, please update the question.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can add iPhone and iPad specific orientation support in info.plist file of your xcode project
Open your info.pList in source code mode and add this

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Using this you can add orientation support whichever screen you want and also can prevent orientation support for particular screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly stop orientation by just click in **project property in xcode** by selecting and deselecting checkbox.(ex. *PORTRAIT*, *LANDSCAPE*)

click on **main project** in xcode and in **General** section you'll get this options.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppDelegate.m`:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (self.allowRotation)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7177423/1604167).

Everyone above, the question is about specific controller orientation locking, not all of them.